# Is there a javascript library to produce the top message ribbon in stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

These ribbon in stackoverflow and uservoice.com looks nice. is there any javascript library/jquery plugin for that effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some tuning, this is a valid equivalent, you receive notifications with fade-in/fade-out effect and it disappears automatically too:

http://projects.zoulcreations.com/jquery/growl/

It is based on the way it looks Growl in Mac: Growl is a notification system for Mac OS X: it allows applications that support Growl to send you notifications.

There is something similar for Mootools:

> http://icebeat.bitacoras.com/mootools/growl/

Answer (score 1):

After some googling i found a similar jquery effect tutorial here http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/07/top-floating-message-box-using-jquery.html